# Polygon Diagonal Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, combinations, polygons

**A diagonal for a polygon is defined as the line segment joining two non-adjacent points. Given an n-sided polygon, how many different diagonals can be drawn for this polygon?**

I know that the number of diagonals is C(n,2). However, I don't know how to account for the fact that you can't draw a diagonal for two points that are adjacent to each other.

Comment: Subtract $n$ from $C(n,2)$

Comment: @Ryan Greyling - how will that work for tetrahedron, as an example?

Comment: I believe the definition of polygon is strictly $2$ dimensional. If you want to talk about higher dimensions then "polytope" would be more accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two easy ways to take that restriction into account. You can start with the number of pairs of vertices, $\binom{n}2$, and subtract the number of pairs of adjacent vertices, $n$. Or you can observe that at each vertex there are $n-3$ other vertices that are not adjacent. That means that each vertex is an end of $n-3$ diagonals, so there are $n(n-3)$ ends of diagonals and therefore $\frac{n(n-3)}2$ diagonals.

As a check,

$$\binom{n}2-n=\frac{n(n-1)}2-n=\frac{n(n-3)}2\;.$$

Comment: Profesor Scott kindly help us with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769180/on-counting-balls-in-an-urn-combinatorics/3769190#3769190

Comment: @James: It's $01:45$ here now, but I'll take a look when I get online tomt.

Comment: thank sir appreciate your time